# Add Some HTML to the Right of #content on Zen 7.5

Tags: theming

Hello ive been struggling with this all morning and i tend to only post here when im really exasperated and used up my css limited knowedgle after pushing the boundaries that bit further.

I have [A WEBPAGE](http://onlinebanter.com/latest) quite standard stuff. Reposinsive design though which could be a bugger to me. #page, #header, #content etc. I was trying to draw a photoshop pic actually i better.....blast i cant. Its easy really. I just want to have a new sidebar on the right of the main content.

Im gonna add this to drupal stackoverflow instead if you dont mind. This could be something to do with block regions. I know i could maybe use block regions but im using panels and i prefer to have no blocks loaded in the blocks bit (for performance) i might just be OCD about it.

Im invoking the block just with code. Ive had it a million places in my page tpl (zen 7.5) and i cant seem to get it anywhere near where the right sidebar should have been.

I might be making an easy question sound hard. I just want to add some html to the right of #content region. thats all. bah this is getting me down. Can anyone shed some light on it for me?

Thanks

The html im adding is

```
    <div id="maleft">
    <?php
      $block = module_invoke('md_megamenu', 'block_view', '2');
      print $block['content'];
    ?>
```

and my css for maleft is none existant as i cant even get it in the contant area :(

Comment: ps currently the menu block im trying to fit snuggly in the top right of the content area and just below the horrible red mess with buttons on it. The block is currently hiding down the bottom of my page. By the time you read ths though it might be anywhere :(

Comment: ***UPDATE*** ive just used the block regions for ease but i'd prefer not to as im only adding that one block in the sidebar. I think it hurts performance using Panels and Blocks. I dont like having to add the Main Content block to content just so as i can add one block which i might be able to hard code into the theme. Thoughts on that appreciated too. thanks

Comment: UPDATE: im not using the block regions as its just over complicating things and ive gave up. Its hard to get things to work at differant resolutions. Ill just keep it all Panel baded for ease unless some css wizz knows a way to do this. I'll even take a coloum, left or right, of page content. Totally seperate fom the #page. Actually that wont work with my responsive design as id need it to flick down below. i need to keep within my capabilities here i think.